# Why rounding corners an image with glide is increasing my ram usage?

Tags: android, performance, android-glide

I created items for a `recyclerview`, which consists of card view with an image view on the inside.

However, it had high GPU overdraw so I switched to using just an image view with `Glide` library for the rounded corners.

The problem is, that ram usage has increased after switching from card view to image view + glide.

what is going on exactly?

Here is my items layout:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/collection_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this is my `glide` code:

```
  fun roundedGlide(context: Context, url: String, imageView: ImageView?) {

    if (imageView != null)
        Glide.with(context)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                        .error(R.drawable.place_holder)
                        .transforms(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(10)).dontAnimate())
                .load(url)
                .into(imageView)

}
```

Comment: Did it increase by the size of the image(s) more or less?  Then its probably caching the pre-transformed and transformed versions.

Comment: I doubt it is increasing the size since I am clipping the image which should reduce its size + the api sends the same image format. @GabeSechan

Comment: I meant did the ram used increase by the size of the image

Comment: Did you find any solution?